# awk or sed: append pattern to existing line after match

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am looking for a sed or awk solution that will insert a string into an existing line in a file after the first match of a pattern. For example I need this:

```
command arg arg2 -o another string and another string and so on
```

to look like this:

```
command "new string here" arg arg2 another string and another string and so on
```

If we match on "command" it would need to only match on the first occurrence of "command".

I prefer not to use a whole line sed substitution solution as the actual line is very long. (and there are multiple lines that I need to modify.) I have come across countless solutions on using sed or awk for appending new lines in a file or appending a string to the end or beginning of a line but have not found a solution yet to insert into the middle of a line like I need to do here.

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code! StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with awk:

```
awk '$1 ~ /command/ { s = ""; for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) s = s $i " "; print $1 " " "new string here" " " s }'
```

Comment: This makes the changes perfectly needed but for me presents another problem in that I can't do an in place modification due to my version of awk and sending a copy to stdout only sends the changes while I need the changes *and* the rest of the file. I will need to post a new question on this.

Comment: You can just redirect the output from the `stdout` to the file with appending `> newfile.txt` to the end of the command.

Comment: That does not work. It still erases the other contents of the file. I am using <my awk script> file > newfile.

Comment: You mean it erases the contents of the file? Is it different from the newfile?

Answer (score 2):

sed version:

```
sed -n 's/^\(command\)\(.*\)/\1 "new string here"\2/p'
```

- s -- substitute
- ^ -- beginning of line
- () -- capture group 1
- command -- literal string
- () -- capture group 2
- .* -- everything else on the line
- \1 -- contents of capture group 1
- "new string here" -- literal string
- \2 -- capture group 2
- p -- print it